# Why does wake-on-lan stop working after some time?

Tags: linux, hardware, wake-on-lan

I have a desktop computer at home that I want to be off when I leave the house, but I want to be able to wake it up remotely if I ever need to, so a few days ago I enabled WOL on it in the BIOS. Using a different computer that runs 24/7 and [this software](https://github.com/remcohaszing/pywakeonlan), I am successfully able to wake it up. Unfortunately, if the computer is off for long enough, it seems that I am no longer able to wake it up with WOL.

Searching the internet, this appears to be a very common problem, and the cause always appears to be the same: people try to use the IP address of the computer they are trying to wake up. This works for the first few minutes while the ARP table has an entry for that IP, but as soon as the entry expires, the machine sending the WOL packets can no longer figure out the destination MAC address, and fails.

When I'm using pywakeonlan, I'm not giving it an IP address - I'm giving it a MAC address as an argument. That means ARP should not be involved in the process, and it shouldn't matter if the ARP table entry expires or not.

Is there something else going on that may cause this problem?

Some article seem to also suggest that instead of using the MAC address of the destination when sending WOL packets, you should do a broadcast. Using FFFFFFFFFFFF didn't work for me either.